# Connection to Openshift Online 3 from JAVA code outside the cloud

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, openshift

Openshift 2 will not work from tomorrow. Online 3 version is available. I use starter type.For Openshift 2 I could write/read data to/from MySQL DB located on openshift from my application that located on my PC, I mean from the code outside of the cloud. But now, with version 3 I have no idea hot to do it. 
How to it now? 
Is it possible to connect my local MySQL WorkBench to MySQL DB on Openshift Online 3 as well?

Answer (score 1):

Port forwarding is very common method to make secure connection to remote machines. Its like creating a secure connection from your machine to the host machine. Once connection is build, any tool like MYSQL workbench can connect via `localhost:<localport>` where  would forward the connection to remote machine's port.

Please read more about this feature [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

The port forwarding can be setup via any shell client supporting the feature, e.g. in a putty configuration.

Openshift V3 also support port forwarding through its client tool `oc`

Step wise:

1) Download and install oc tool. [Refer here.](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html#installing-the-cli)

2) Once install on your machine (windows/linux), you could use port forwarding feature to access it from local machine.

Please refer [openshift document here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/port_forwarding.html) to setup port forward.

Once port forward is setup, leave the console open on local and try connecting to `localhost:<localport>` and you should actually get connected to MYSQL on openshift.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with port-forwarding:

https://katacoda.com/graham.dumpleton/courses/intro-openshift/port-forwarding